# JSon Find multiple specific Values multiple times in C#

Tags: c#, json, findall

I want to search or iterate a pretty huge JSon and find 3 key-value pairs every time they appear. Is there any method or function that could help me doing that? Or is it even possible?

I need to find the first value and from that point on the second, afterwards the third and then the first again.
I know there is FindAll for strings, but it's not that nice to handle a JSon as a string.

Edit: I am using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is massive then I'd recommend streaming the content in and processing it.

For this you can use `JsonTextReader` - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm

```
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    File.WriteAllText(filePath, "{bigJson: true}");

    var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream));
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.Value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", reader.TokenType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! My next problem is, that i'm reading the JSon out of a database by Npqsql with it's own reader. I don't want to process this massive JSon twice, do you know how i possibly could do the same with a non-JSon reader?

Comment: There should be a way to couple the 2 together, I've not used that so unsure.

Comment: I found out how it works, I just read the JSon from my database and while I read it, I  process it with a JsonTextReader-StringReader. It's still more ressources than i wanted to use, but I can't see a better or easier solution.